# Fraction number converted Date and month in Extjs Grid CSV export

Tags: csv, extjs, export-to-csv

Fraction number converted Date and month in Extjs Grid CSV export.

In the extjs grid, I have data like 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, etc. It's displaying properly in the extjs grid. But while converting CSV export, I could see 01-Feb, 01-Mar, and 01-Apr.

But this is working fine in XLSX format.

Can you please help me on this?

Please check the output at the below Fiddle link.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3qbb&view/editor

### Grid output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqWm6.png)

### CSV Export output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIhKp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your data contains string values, not numbers:

```
var myData = [
  ['1/2'],  
  ['1/3'],
  ['1/4'],
  ['Alcoa Inc']
];
```

In the CSV file it looks like:

```
Company
"1/2"
"1/3"
"1/4"
"Alcoa Inc"
```

When you open the CSV file directly with Excel, it tries to guess the data type and will interpret these as dates.

So instead of opening the file with Excel, try to import it to an empty workbook using `File/Import` menu. During the import, there will be a step where you can set a specific data type for the column. Here, instead of the default `General`, select `Text` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i need to converted while click the CSV button from application.

Comment: I am afraid you can't do that with the current data format. If you convert these to numbers (0.5,0.33,0.25) it will work but the string values will become dates when Excel thinks these are dates.

Comment: Did you try "1 / 2" instead of "1/2"?